# Best way to schedule Django command that needs root access

Tags: django, permissions, cron, raspberry-pi, django-commands

I am using a Raspberry Pi as a (very simple) home weather station.

I currently have a small python script that, when run, takes a temperature reading and posts the result as a new line to a Google Spreadsheet via the Google Docs API.  This python script needs to be run as root, and I currently get good results by scheduling this script to run every hour in the superuser's crontab.

I have also just gotten this Pi to run Nginix and uWsgi to serve up Django-powered websites and I'd like to start logging the temperatures to a local database in addition to the Google Spreadsheet.  I would like to do this via Django's ORM since it's what I am most familiar with.

I have two specific goals:

1. Set up a regularly scheduled task that will both post a newly-taken temperature reading to the local DB (using the Django ORM) as well as the Google Spreadsheet.
2. Serve a web page (presumably requiring a login) that will allow remote users to "take a temperature reading now" and both report the result back (via a webpage) and insert the result into the server-side DB.

My question is: What is the best way to do this, knowing that any code that will access the temperature probe must be run as root?

For #1, I guess the question boils down to: what's the best way to load up a python environment that "feels like the Django shell" in that it can easily do all the same imports (specifically things like the ORM)?  If I could do that, I could write a new script that would do both the Spreadsheet upload and the DB write.  Can I/should I do this via a Django "Command" that would then be scheduled to run in the superuser's crontab?  Or should I do this via a regular old python script that goes ahead and loads the right Django-specific modules?

For #2, I was looking for suggestions about how to handle the "must run as root" issue for the temperature sensor readings.  I clearly don't want to run the whole Django process as root.  So what are my best options here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[django-celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) is the definitely worth looking into for running scheduled tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Do you have a reference I could look at for how to run the celery tasks with root access?

Comment: It's not something I've done myself, but under [this section](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#starting-the-worker-process) it talks about running the celery worker as a deamon, which I imagine you could give root access to.

Comment: From what I've read, Celery is really overkill for this.  I think I'm leaning more towards making an executable shell script and allowing it (and it alone) to be run as root via the sudoers file.  But it's not something I've done and I'd love to hear from anyone who has dealt with this sort of thing in the past.  More generally, I'd still love to hear the "best" way to write python code that can access the Django ORM.  Is it just start the script with putting the relevant directory on the python path and then do the imports as normal?